# How to change views in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm coming from ASP.NET background and I have trouble understanding a couple of things in WinForms. When I want to go to a different "view" in ASP.NET I just go to a different page and do something there with my code.

How does it work in WinForms? Let's say I have a menu with various buttons on it and I want to show a different set of data in some control (DataGridView).

Do I stay on the same form and read the value of the pressed button and then act on it(e.g. bind the grid)? Or do I go to a different form?

I am interested in both code and various approaches all of you might have, best practices, whatever...

Comment: To quote the FAQ: `If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.`

Comment: I understand you, and I try to get to an answer on my own, but this time I just didn't know where to look so I came to see you guys.

Comment: Compare your situation with desktop applications you've used in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely, a "view" would correspond to a `Form` object. The form object is a top-level window hosting some UI (much like the web browser is a top-level window hosting some UI). Having an application show & hide multiple top-level forms other than dialog boxes can be disconcerting, so your "main" form is the basis for your primary user interaction.

If you have a menu with buttons on it, the code responding to menu commands being selected can update (say) a `DataGridView` control on that form, or show a dialog box to gather additional information, etc.

Comment: But wouldn't such an approach generate a huge Form class? I mean, suppose you have a bunch of menus, each with 5-8 buttons, that adds up. And if each one would bind the grid in a different way you'd end up with dozens of methods. Or is that still OK?

Comment: Thats fine and to be expected for many applications that encompass a decent amount of functionality.

Comment: ...and at this point we can start talking about application architecture - how this form is just a shell to interact with the user, and the real work of determining what data to display gets delegated to some business logic layer classes.

Comment: @robotron - IF they all use the same grid, then yes.  If they start having different functionality, you might want to make a MDI application and have new forms open within the main form.